# What's the difference between the spin matrix and the generator of the Poincaré algebra?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, field-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

Searching for articles and research papers on the Poincaré gauge theory, I found https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0302040 a good three lectures of Blagojevich on the subject.

So straight away on the second page, it says that the action of global Poincaré transformations in a tangent space $T_p$ transforms frames between each other, inducing an appropriate transformation of the fields $\phi(x)$ $$x'^i=x^i+\omega^i_{\ j} x^j+\epsilon^i \implies \phi'(x')= (1+\frac{1}{2} \omega^{ij} \Sigma_{ij})\phi(x)$$
and he names the $\Sigma_{ij}$ the spin matrix. My first question is: If the $\omega_{ij}$ are the parameters of rotation, then the last expression is a representation of the Lorentz group in the space of n-uplets that are matter fields, my remark is that there is no information of the translation group in this expression even though they assume the implication from the coordinate transformation. Can someone explain to me how is it possible?

Then he says "**Equivalently** we can write" $$\delta_0\phi=(\frac{1}{2}\omega^{ij}M_{ij}+\epsilon^kP_k)\phi$$ where the $\delta_0\phi=\phi'(x)-\phi(x)$ and the $M_{ij}=x_i\partial_j-x_j\partial_i+\Sigma_{ij}$. We can clearly see that the spin matrix is only involved in rotations. So my second question is: how is this equivalent because here it's literally a Poincaré transformation on fields and in the previous one it's a transformation on fields induced by a **rotation** on Minkowski coordinates.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: By "rotation", you mean "Lorentz tfmation" including the 0 index as well, no? Indeed, the matrix Σ merely Lorentz transforms φ; its translation is effected by shifting its argument coordinates only. So Σ scrambles the various components of φ the same way at all points of these argument coordinates. Taking  φ  to be a spinor,  Σ is just proportional to Dirac's $[\gamma^i,\gamma^j]$ you might know about.

Comment: So correct me if I misunderstood your explanation, a global Poincaré transformation   $\delta x=\omega x+\epsilon$ could be just seen as a linear transformation A.K.A a Lorentz transformation of a matter field on any point determined by the affine transformation on the vector space(Minkowski space).

Comment: Yes; the spin matrix has nothing to do with Poincare translations.

Comment: thank you for your explanation.